# How to fix setParameters Failed in Android.harware.Camera?

Tags: android-camera, face-detection

**Hi**

I am getting this error on multiple devices,

> setParameters Failed

...while creating a camera app in Android.

*What causes this problem?*

**Here's what I have done so far on opening `camera` setting the `Parameters`:**

```
   public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder ) {



        try {

                camera = camera.open();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "failed to open Camera");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {

            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();


        }catch (Exception e){



        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        refreshCamera();
        setDisplayOrientation();

        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

        camera.setFaceDetectionListener(faceDetectionListener);
        camera.startFaceDetection();
        parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
        List<Camera.Size> customSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Camera.Size customSize = customSizes.get(0); //Added size
        parameters.setPreviewSize(customSize.width, customSize.height);
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();





    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.stopPreview();
        }

    }




    public void frontCamera(View view) {

        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera=null;

        if (cameraId == 0){



            try {

                camera = camera.open(1);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "failed to open Camera");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            android.hardware.Camera.Parameters parameters;
            camera.setFaceDetectionListener(faceDetectionListener);
            camera.startFaceDetection();
            parameters = camera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
            List<Camera.Size> customSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();


            Camera.Size customSize = customSizes.get(0); //Added size
            parameters.setPreviewSize(customSize.width, customSize.height);
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

            cameraId = 1;


            try {

                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();


            }catch (Exception e){



            }
        }
```

**+** I've tried to do research on the internet and I found this:

```
  List<Camera.Size> customSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();


            Camera.Size customSize = customSizes.get(0); //Added size
            parameters.setPreviewSize(customSize.width, customSize.height);
```

But still causing the `setParameters` error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Do you know the cameras in question support FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE?** That's not guaranteed. Check [getSupportedFocusModes()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedFocusModes()). A camera can fail setParameters if you use a non-supported mode of any type.
- **Do you know the camera supports a frame rate of 20?** That's not guaranteed. Check [getSupportedPreviewFpsRange](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewFpsRange()). Again, a camera can fail setParameters if you a non-supported frame rate value.
- **And, as Jan says, [startFaceDetection()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#startFaceDetection()) should be called only after preview is started**. Though it's a bit surprising that doing that out of order will result in a setParameters error, in all honesty.

Answer (score 1):

Your method *`startFaceDetection()`* SHOULD be called after the preview is started because the camera will notify *`Camera.FaceDetectionListener`* of the detected faces in the preview frame.

```
        parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
        List<Camera.Size> customSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Camera.Size customSize = customSizes.get(0); //Added size
        parameters.setPreviewSize(customSize.width, customSize.height);
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();

camera.setFaceDetectionListener(faceDetectionListener);
        camera.startFaceDetection();
```

Comment: Great! But just asking, should I use the startPreview(); and  camera.setParameters(parameters); inside try and catch with like Exeption e or IOExeption e?

Comment: THX! Here you go!

Comment: Its still getting some errors with same titles... sorry but this didnt solvecmy problem quite yet... but thanks for giving an advice

Comment: Ok no problem, best of luck! :)